# Tomcat: Remotely deploy service programmatically

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I'm trying to make a service that would deploy WAR file on tomcat server. The class takes input as the path of WAR file and automatically deploys it to the tomcat server once this class in run following is the code.    kindly help me with this. also I don't want to use SFTP to upload the WAR while but instead use put request to deploy the WAR file on tomcat. I have seen examples of using FTP or SFTP for the same but that is what I don't require.

```
public class DeployManager {

static CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();;

public static void main(String args[]) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    /*
     * warning only ever AuthScope.ANY while debugging with these settings
     * the tomcat username and pw are added to EVERY request
     */

    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat", "s3cret"));
    deploy();
    // undeploy();
}

private static void deploy() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=C:/Users/Jainesh_Trivedi/Desktop/WAR/AutohostDemo1_1145.war";
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Jainesh_Trivedi\\Desktop\\WAR\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");

    HttpPut req = new HttpPut(url);
    MultipartEntityBuilder meb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    meb.addTextBody("Sample", "C:\\Users\\Jainesh_Trivedi\\Desktop\\WAR\\AutohostDemo1_1145.war");

    // "application/octect-stream"
    meb.addBinaryBody("attachment", file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, file.getName());

    req.setEntity(meb.build());
    String response = executeRequest(req, credsProvider);

    System.out.println("Response : " + response);
}

public static void undeploy() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/deployMe";
    HttpGet req = new HttpGet(url);
    String response = executeRequest(req, credsProvider);
    System.out.println("Response : " + response);
}

private static String executeRequest(HttpRequestBase requestBase, CredentialsProvider credsProvider)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
    InputStream responseStream = null;
    String res = null;
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestBase);
    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
    responseStream = responseEntity.getContent();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    br.close();
    res = sb.toString();

    return res;
}
}
```

Error is:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Nov 24, 2015 10:39:23 AM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:150)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:173)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:97)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.invoke(CPoolProxy.java:138)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.sendRequestEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:77)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.autohost.java.DeployManager.executeRequest(DeployManager.java:68)
    at com.autohost.java.DeployManager.deploy(DeployManager.java:51)
    at com.autohost.java.DeployManager.main(DeployManager.java:35)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to deploy war on tomcat. I would suggest using maven for it. If you are already using maven in your project then use tomcat plugin. It will create a war for you and deploy it on tomcat.

Assuming that you are using Tomcat 7. Add following in your `<build>` tag of pom.xml.

```
     <build>
        <finalName>AutohostDemo1_1145</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/AutohostDemo1_1145</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Keep your tomcat running. Fetch all the latest code from repository. And then run following command from root directory (directory that contains pom.xml file) of your project.

```
mvn tomcat7:redeploy
```

This command will create a war file and deploy it to tomcat. We don't even need to manually restart tomcat.

In case if you want to perform this action on remote server, then you can clone your repository on server once. After that whenever you need to deploy a new war on tomcat, then you can connect using telnet & from root directory of project (on remote server) run the same command.

Comment: actually my webservice would already be deployed on server, my requirement is on calling my service and supplying the WAR file path it should get deployed on the tomcat server